# How do I initialize the whitelist for Apache-Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm new to Apache Kafka.
I've installed it into a Ubuntu Linux VM (18.04).

**I've started up Zookeeper from the Kafka directory with the default configuration.**
[image: Apache Kafka Startup]

The Zookeeper looks like it started successfully.
From another Terminal window I am attempting to test.
I'm connecting to it with Telnet and am attempting to send a "stat" command.

**When I do so, I get the following error message:**
[image: Zookeeper Error Message]

I'm a newbie to Apache/kafka and have limited linux experience.
I googled around but it wasn't really clear to me how to update the whitelist.

I found the following snippet from Zookeeper documentation:

> 4lw.commands.whitelist (Java system property:
> zookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist)
>
> New in 3.4.10: This property contains a list of comma separated Four
> Letter Words commands. It is introduced to provide fine grained
> control over the set of commands ZooKeeper can execute, so users can
> turn off certain commands if necessary. By default it contains all
> supported four letter word commands except "wchp" and "wchc", if the
> property is not specified. If the property is specified, then only
> commands listed in the whitelist are enabled.
>
> Here's an example of the configuration that enables stat, ruok, conf,
> and isro command while disabling the rest of Four Letter Words
> command:
> 4lw.commands.whitelist=stat, ruok, conf, isro
> Users can also use asterisk option so they don't have to include every command one by one in the list. As an example, this
> will enable all four letter word commands:
> 4lw.commands.whitelist=*

Can someone please explain the whitelist usage and how to correctly initialize it?

Thanks, JohnB

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me; setting the environment variable on the command line.

```
KAFKA_OPTS="-Dzookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist=*" bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 29):

For me, adding one of the following lines (or a variation) to the `config/zookeeper.properties` file (in the installation folder) worked.

- `4lw.commands.whitelist=stat, ruok, conf, isro`
- `4lw.commands.whitelist=*`

Comment: thanks. it works for me! but...
in latest version (3.6.3) there is another path to property file
`conf/zoo.cfg`

Answer (score 8):

For mac, I added

**4lw.commands.whitelist=stat, ruok, conf, isro**

in **/usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg**

Answer (score 0):

If zookeeper has been pulled through docker, use the below command to run the container:

```
docker run -e "ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST=*" --name zc --restart always -d zookeeper
```